# How to make a hover effect on a particular card and stops hovering on remaining cards?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

if i hover on a card one it displays the icons of every card but i want to display icons on a particular hovering card (ouput of my card-[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5OxU.png)).These cards are automatically generated by using v-for and fetch the data from axios package,DisplayNotes.vue file responsibility is to show the notes to the user in the cards ,please help me to fix this issue.`

[DisplayNotes.vue]

```
<template>
<div class="main-section">
    <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.data" class="container">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p><i>{{note.body}}</i></p>
        </div>
        <div @mouseover="hover=true" @mouseleave="hover=false" class="import-icons">
            <icons v-if="hover" />
            <button type="button" @click="handlesubmit()">close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
export default {
    components: {
        icons
    },
    data() {
        return {
            hover: false,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited Notes...'
            }, ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async handlesubmit() {
           const response = await axios.get('/displayNotes', {});
            localStorage.getItem('token', response.data.token);
           this.notes.push(response.data);
        },
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">

.card-content {
    input {
        border: none;
    }
    textarea {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }
}
/* dividing the width percentage */
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
    margin: -2.98%; 
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-style: ridge;
}
.import-icons {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -2%;
    padding-top: 25%;

    button {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        float: right;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-top: -2%;
        padding-left: 400px;
    }
}

</style>
```

[icons.vue]

```
<template>
<div class="used-icons">
    <i id="first-icon" class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    <i id="second-icon" class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i id="third-icon" class="fas fa-palette"></i>
    <i id="forth-icon" class="fas fa-archive"></i>
    <!-- <i id="fifth-icon" class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i> -->
</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
#first-icon {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#second-icon {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#third-icon {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#forth-icon {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#fifth-icon {
    padding-right: 195px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the items are conditionally rendered on the same `hover` property, so whenever that property is true (when an item is hovered), all items are shown instead of only the hovered one.

One way to fix this is to add `hover` to each `notes[]` array element, and use that to conditionally render them:

```html
<div v-for="note in notes">
  <div @mouseover="note.hover=true" @mouseleave="note.hover=false">
    <icons v-if="note.hover" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // hover: false, // remove this
      notes: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Fundoo',
          body: 'unlimited Notes...',
          hover: false, // add this
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Fundoo',
          body: 'unlimited Notes...'
          hover: false, // add this
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
```

To add `hover` property to new `notes[]` array elements in `handlesubmit()`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async handlesubmit() {
      //...
      this.notes.push({
        ...response.data,
        hover: false,
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your implementation I consider you add 'hover' property to each card and then manipulate it in event handlers.

```
<template>
  <div class="main-section">
    <div v-for="(note, index) in notes" :key="note.data" class="container">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p><i>{{note.body}}</i></p>
        </div>
        <div @mouseover="note[index].hover=true" @mouseleave="note[index].hover = false" class="import-icons">
            <icons v-if="hover" />
            <button type="button" @click="handlesubmit()">close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            hover: false,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited Notes...',
                hover: false
            }, ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async handlesubmit() {
           const response = await axios.get('/displayNotes', {});
            localStorage.getItem('token', response.data.token);
           this.notes.push(response.data);
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with only CSS, no JavaScript required.

Add a `note` class to the note container and `note-icons` to the icons element.

Then with some simple css we can conditionally show the `note-icons` on hover.

```css
.note-icons {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.note:hover .note-icons
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Full Snippet

```
<template>
<div class="main-section">
    <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.data" class="container note"> <!-- ⭐️ -->
        <div class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p><i>{{note.body}}</i></p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="note-icons"/> <!-- ⭐️ -->
            <button type="button" @click="handlesubmit()">close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
export default {
    components: {
        icons
    },
    data() {
        return {
            hover: false,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited Notes...'
            }, ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async handlesubmit() {
           const response = await axios.get('/displayNotes', {});
            localStorage.getItem('token', response.data.token);
           this.notes.push(response.data);
        },
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">

.card-content {
    input {
        border: none;
    }
    textarea {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }
}
/* dividing the width percentage */
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
    margin: -2.98%; 
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-style: ridge;
}
.import-icons {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -2%;
    padding-top: 25%;

    button {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        float: right;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-top: -2%;
        padding-left: 400px;
    }
}

.note-icons { /* ⭐️ */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.note:hover .note-icons { /* ⭐️ */
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```